# How to use FB.Event.Subscribe securely to call webservice

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking at using the FB.event.subscribe method to get a notification whenever someone leaves a comment in the FB comment plugin.

However, I want to use Ajax to call a webservice I've exposed on my server to keep track of (a) What was commented on (b) who left the comment.

I have the following questions and was hoping to get some help:

1. Does the what information does the FB.event.subscribe give me to my function?  The FB [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) is totally anemic and doesn't give enough detail.  For example, I want to know WHO left the comment.
2. If I call a webservice, say to insert a row in my DB to keep track of comments, such as what the comment is and what datetime it was left.  If I use Ajax to just call a web service, how do I do it securely?  Since it's ajax, anyone can view source and see the endpoint I'm calling.  I can't use a token since that's exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 1:
You can do below snippet to find out what you get from facebook api while firebug's  console window is opening.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Answer to question 2:
You might need to implement your own security mechanism to secure the webservice you have. It can be done by checking a token when it be called or whatever something else.

Comment: Thanks for answer to question 1.  A related question: can I pass in extra parameters to function? i.e. `function(response, "1234")`?

For question 2, I don't know what security to implement because the code is exposed to the client.  I can't HTTP referer since that can be forge.

Comment: Since the function is a callback function that facebook will call it with a response parameter for you when it has finished. So You can't pass any extra parameters to the function.